# If two atoms collide then will one of their electrons be excited, always?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, energy, atomic-physics, collision

Over here,
https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/702561907961233459/714002823876182096/IMG_20200524_120155.jpg

In the solution to this question, it says that maximum kinetic energy change occurs when the energy goes into exciting one of the hydrogen's electron into a higher energy state. What is the mechanism of this? And when does this happen?

My work:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Collisional_excitation

I found this but I'm not sure how to apply the concept in this Wikipedia article to solve this question?

Answer (score 2):

Electrons in atoms are bound states, having different energies depending on the energy level they occupy. In hydrogen, the only electron present, is bound to the proton with a bounding energy of $13.6$ eV. This quantity has been theoretically predicted and measured. What this means is that, if you give the hydrogen atom precisely $13.6$ eV, you can give that energy to the electron which escapes the atom.

In your question there's an error since you say that "energy goes into exciting one of the hydrogens electron into a higher energy state." but $13.6$ eV does not excite the electron to an higher energy states, it kicks it out of its bound state with the proton. In a collision between two hydrogen atoms, it their combined energy is $13.6$ eV you'll get the following $$H+H \to H+H^++e^-$$ It does not matter in which way you give energy to the electron, but it must be $13.6$ eV. If the two hydrogens colliding have a total of $20$ eV, for example, $13.6$ eV of that energy will go to the extraction of the electron from one of the hydrogen atoms, the rest goes into kinetic energy of either of the outgoing particles after the collision.

All of this process is governed, and explained by quantum mechanics. You can find many references on the internet.

But in my opinion that question is not well-posed, since even the answer $27.2$ eV could be a good answer, since is twice the first ionization energy of the electron, and so you'll get a process like $$H+H \to 2H^+ +2e^-$$

Answer (score 1):

> If two atoms collide then will one of their electrons be excited, always?

Atoms are in the quntum mechanical regime,which means one can predict **probability** of interactions when two atoms collide, which will depend on the initial conditions of energy and momentum entering into the scattering. So there is no unique answer to the title question, one of the electrons might , or might not go to a high energy level.

Let us take hydrogen as a simple atom, and the Bohr picture, because it is consistent with the quantum mechanical solution as far as measurements of interactions go. One has to keep in mind that the orbits shown are caricatures of [the orbitals](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/Chemical/eleorb.html)( probability loci) of the quantum  mechanical solutions.

[image: hydrbohr]

These are the possible energy levels that an electron can be captured in by the proton, to make a hydrogen atom. The stable level is the ground level, but an excited atom can exist as long as the exact(within the width of the line, but that is another story) energy in the form of a photon  kicks the electron to a higher level.

Now if two hydrogen atoms collide, suppose both in the ground state, the quantum mechanical calculation has many probable outputs, depending on the energy and the angle of collision.

> In the solution to this question, it says that maximum kinetic energy change occurs when the energy goes into exciting one of the hydrogen's electron into a higher energy state. What is the mechanism of this? And when does this happen

The atoms have spill over electric fields, i.e. the electron does not shield completely the proton, so instantaneously, one can calculate an interaction between the spill over field of the two atoms,  which exchange [a virtual photon](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/Particles/expar.html) and may:

1) scatter elastically, i.e. change direction and the state of the electron remains unchanged. This has a calculable with quantum mechanics probability of happening

2) The exchanged virtual photon is absorbed by one of the atoms and one of the electrons is kicked up to a higher energy level. If it is not  the ionization level, i.e. the 16.6keV, but a still bound level, the kinetic energy will be diminished by a smaller amount consistent with the difference in the two levels. The maximum energy that can be absorbed by one of the atoms, is the 13.6 keV so one of them becomds it becomes an ion.

BTW it is better not to use kinetic energies, but stick to the four vector  energy and momentum. Then calculations are kept Lorentz invariant.